# Schema XSD: Element Unique inside a node, not repeated values

Tags: xml, xsd, unique, validation, field

I would like to validate a XML file with a schema for that values in the same node can't be repeated. It's important the order of the signatures. My invalid XML is:

```
   <person>
      <name>Peter Petrelli</name>
      <subject1>Mathematics</subject1>
      <note1>8.5</note1>
      <subject2>Natural Science</subject2>
      <note2>4.5</note2>
      <subject3>Mathematics</subject3>
      <note3>7</note3>
   </person>
</school>
```

It's not possible Mathematics is more than once.

How can i validate this with a XSD schema?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a more sensible design there would be no problem:

```
<person>
<name>Peter Petrelli</name>
<subject>
    <name>Mathematics</name>
    <note>2</note>
</subject>
<subject>
    <name>Natural Sciences</name>
    <note>2.5</note>
</subject>
<subject>
    <name>Mathematics</name>
    <note>4</note>
</subject>
```

then the <unique> definition inside the <person> element could be:

```
    <unique name="su">
        <selector xpath="subject" />
        <field xpath="name"/>
    </unique>
```

Comment: Indeed. Your use of element names containing the suffix -1, -2, -3 etc seems to make writing a sensible XSD schema virtually impossible. It will also make any processing of the XML (e.g. using XSLT or XPath) vastly more difficult. It's a very poor design.

Comment: I have only written an small example, but i have changed my design following our recommendations and from now i can validate properly. Thank you very much, Folks